# firebase-queue - worker not lauching when defining specs

Tags: firebase-queue

I m using firebase-queue and I want to use the specs functionnality. I did the following :

-server side :

```
var queueRef = firebase.database().ref('queue');
queueRef.child('specs').set({
        register: {
            start_state : 'register_user',
            in_progress_state: 'register_user_in_progress',
            timeout: 1000
        }
    });

    var optionRegister = {
        specId : 'register',
        numWorkers: 1
    };

    //my worker
    var registerQueue = new Queue(queueRef,optionRegister,function(data, progress, resolve, reject) {
      // Read and process task data
      console.log(data);
    });
```

-client side :

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref('queue/tasks');
ref.push({ '_start': 'register_user', 'id': user1 });
```

In the firebase database, I see the task and the specs are correctly added :
[my database view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hxoP9.png)

-Versions
Node.js v7.0.0
firebase v3.5.3
firebase-queue v1.5.0

The problem is that the task is never taken by the worker and I cannot find why. Can anyone help me ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Everything seems correct except, '_start' object. It's actually '_state' object. Try changing this. Hope this will help.

```
ref.push({ '_state': 'register_user', 'id': user1 });
```